# renderParts error in mime-mail package

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am trying to figure out how to send an email message through `AWS SES` using [`mime-mail-ses`](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/master/demo/auth/email_auth_ses_mailer.hs#L114) package. I used `renderSendMailSES` example from [`Yesod wiki`](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/master/demo/auth/email_auth_ses_mailer.hs#L114) to try the code below - I am using `renderMail` here to debug the error in `mail` body validation:

```
    *Main> let textPart = Part {partType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8", 
partEncoding = None, partFilename = Nothing, partHeaders = [], partContent = "Testing"}
    *Main> let htmlPart = Part { partType = "text/html; charset=utf-8", 
partEncoding = None, partFilename = Nothing, partHeaders = [], partContent = "Testing"}
    *Main> renderMail' (emptyMail $ Address Nothing "noreply@example.com") {
 mailTo = [Address Nothing "test@example.com"] , mailHeaders =  [ ("Subject", 
"Testing email address")], mailParts = [[textPart, htmlPart]]}
```

I get this error:

```
*** Exception: renderParts called with null parts
```

This is quite head-scratcher because the above example doesn't seem any different from `Yesod Wiki`. I can't add attachment either because of the above error. An attachment if I am not mistaken, will look like this for `mailParts`:

```
mailParts = [[textPart,htmlPart],[attachment1]]
```

I looked in the code that is causing the error but can't figure out what is wrong.

I will very much appreciate pointers to resolve this error.

Comment: You mean the "mime-mail-ses" package, correct?

Comment: @RowanBlush, yep, correct. Fixed it.

Comment: Hm... I can't reproduce! [gist](https://gist.github.com/e1876b24d0e856dacd2c1dbe6f8161b5). Do you get the same error if you load my parts.hs in GHCi and attempt to show `rendered`? If so I would guess it has to be a versioning issue...

Comment: @RowanBlush, indeed versioning issue. Fixed, and posted in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a versioning issue. I had a local patched copy of `http-client` from github (to add some streaming validation that wasn't in `stackage` yet) which seems to be the culprit here. I fixed it by changing the http-client to point to `http-client` on stackage with the release version that had my fixes (`0.4.31`). Now, it works fine.